# Annual, monthly or daily mean for irregular time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am a new user of "R", and I couldn't find a good solution to solve it. I got a timeseries in the following format:

```
>dates  temperature depth   salinity
>12/03/2012 11:26   9.7533  0.48073 37.607
>12/03/2012 11:56   9.6673  0.33281 37.662
>12/03/2012 12:26   9.6673  0.33281 37.672
```

I have an irregular frequency for variable measurements, done every 15 or every 30 minutes depending on the period. I would like to calculate annual, monthly and daily averages for each of my variables, whatever the number of data in a day/month/year is. I read a lot of things about the packages zoo, timeseries, xts, etc. but I can't get a clear vision of what I nead (maybe cause I'm not skilled enough with R...).

I hope my post is clear, don't hesitate to tell me if it's not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert your data to an xts object, then use `apply.daily` et al to calculate whatever values you want.

```
library(xts)
d <- structure(list(dates = c("12/03/2012 11:26", "12/03/2012 11:56", 
"12/03/2012 12:26"), temperature = c(9.7533, 9.6673, 9.6673), 
    depth = c(0.48073, 0.33281, 0.33281), salinity = c(37.607, 
    37.662, 37.672)), .Names = c("dates", "temperature", "depth", 
"salinity"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
x <- xts(d[,-1], as.POSIXct(d[,1], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
apply.daily(x, colMeans)
#                     temperature     depth salinity
# 2012-12-03 12:26:00    9.695967 0.3821167   37.647
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The advantage is that with xts I can ask for weekly averages. I tried your code, I get some issues with my entire dataset so I try to fix it and I'll keep you in touch ! Thank you again !

Comment: It's ok, day and month were just inverted (%m/%d >>> %d/%m). Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I'd add the day, month and year into the data frame and then use `aggregate()`.

First convert your `date` column into a POSIXct objet:

```
d$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(d$dates,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz ="GMT")
```

Then get the date (e.g. 12/03/2012) into a column called `Date`, try this:

```
d$Date <- format(d$timestamp,"%y-%m-%d",tz = "GMT")
```

Next, aggregate by the date:

```
aggregate(cbind("temperature.mean" = temperature,
                "salinity.mean" = salinity) ~ Date,
          data = d,
          FUN = mean)
```

Similarly, you can get the month into a column (let's call it `M` for month), and then...

```
d$M <- format(d$timestamp,"%B",tz = "GMT")

aggregate(cbind("temperature.mean" = temperature,
                "salinity.mean" = salinity) ~ M,
          data = d,
          FUN = mean)
```

or if you want year-month

```
d$YM <- format(d$timestamp,"%y-%B",tz = "GMT")

aggregate(cbind("temperature.mean" = temperature,
                "salinity.mean" = salinity) ~ YM,
          data = d,
          FUN = mean)
```

If you have any NA values in your data, you may need to account for those:

```
aggregate(cbind("temperature.mean" = temperature,
                "salinity.mean" = salinity) ~ YM,
          data = d,
          function(x) mean(x,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Finally, if you want to average by week, you can do that as well. First generate the week number, and then use `aggregate()` again.

```
d$W <- format(d$timestamp,"%W",tz = "GMT")

aggregate(cbind("temperature.mean" = temperature,
                "salinity.mean" = salinity) ~ W,
          data = d,
          function(x) mean(x,na.rm = TRUE))
```

This version of week number defines week 1 as being the week with the first Monday of the year. The weeks are from Monday to Sunday.

Comment: Your calls to `format` won't work. The `dates` column is not a `POSIXct` object. It's either a character or (more likely) a factor.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Noted. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! This works perfectly after a change I also did for answer 1 (day and month inverted, I guess it's a difference of country, cause in France we give the day before the month ;). Like I asked to Jdbaba, is there a way to calculate weekly averages with the library player like for the xts library ?

Answer (score 1):

Yet, another method using plyr:

```
df <- structure(list(dates = c("12/03/2012 11:26", "12/03/2012 11:56", 
   "12/03/2012 12:26"), temperature = c(9.7533, 9.6673, 9.6673), 
   depth = c(0.48073, 0.33281, 0.33281), salinity = c(37.607, 
   37.662, 37.672)), .Names = c("dates", "temperature", "depth",                                                                                                
  "salinity"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

library(plyr)

# Change date to POSIXct
df$dates <- with(d,as.POSIXct(dates,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))

# Make new variables, year and month
df <- transform(d,month=as.numeric(format(dates,"%m")),year=as.numeric(format(dates,"%Y")))

## According to year
ddply(df,.(year),summarize,meantemp=mean(temperature),meandepth=mean(depth),meansalinity=mean(salinity))
  year meantemp meandepth meansalinity
1 2012 9.695967 0.3821167       37.647

## According to month
ddply(df,.(month),summarize,meantemp=mean(temperature),meandepth=mean(depth),meansalinity=mean(salinity))
  month meantemp meandepth meansalinity
1    12 9.695967 0.3821167       37.647
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! This works perfectly after a change I also did for answer 1 (day and month inverted, I guess it's a difference of country, cause in France we give the day before the month ;). Is there a way to calculate weekly averages with the library player like for the xts library ?

Answer (score 1):

The package `hydroTSM` holds a multiple functions to creat annual and other summaries:

```
daily2annual(x, ...)
subdaily2annual(x, ...)
monthly2annual(x, ...)
annualfunction(x, FUN, na.rm = TRUE, ...)
```