# Splitting Dataframe in R, work on with splits and save in new dataframe

Tags: r, time-series

i'm quite new to R and have the following problem:

I work with meteorologic data (temperature and percipitation). The data was quantified every half our over one year. So i have a dataframe with about 17520 rows.
My first column contents the date in the form: `"year-month-day hour:minute:second"`

Now i want to get only one value for my parameters for each day, which means, i need to average every day.

I managed to split the dataframe by date with the following expression:

```
split(data, as.Date(data$DATE))
```

But now i have the problem that i dont have any clue how to work on with that split. If i want to save it, i only get some kind of list.
Has anyone an idea, how i can work on with my splitted data, which means, how can i average the values for each day and merge the averaged day-values to a new dataframe containing only one row for each day of the year.

I hope i described the problem quite sufficient.
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: See joshuas answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658274/annual-monthly-or-daily-mean-for-irregular-time-series

Comment: EDi's link is good for doing this with time series data. The more generic version is the split-apply-combine approach implemented in the `plyr` package (though that is not the only way; you have the split part, `lapply` can give you the apply-over-each-partition-of-the-split part, and `rbind` (or some variant) can re-combine them).

Answer (score 0):

Generally as noted in the link, `xts` is a good package to deal with time series. Another option is to use `data.table` package. Here I compare the 2 packages's performance computing daily mean of a time series.

```
## needed package
library(data.table)
library(xts)
library(microbenchmark)
## create the data, here I am using yearly index with half an hour frequency
set.seed(1)
time = seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct('2013-01-01',tz=''),
                  to=as.POSIXct('2013-12-31',tz=''),
                  by = as.difftime(0.5,units="hours"))
value= runif(n = length(time), min = 18, max = 54)
## the data.table object
DT <- data.table(time=time,value=value)
## the time series
xtt <- xts(x=value,time)
```

I compute the daily mean using data.table and xts. For data.table I use 2 methods: first method create the grouping factor (day) , second method use the grouping factor already crated.

```
## compute daily mean using data.table
dt.m <- function()
  DT[,day:=format(time,'%d-%m-%Y')][,mean(value),day]
## using data.table but the grouping variable is already created
dt.withday.m <- function()
  DT[,mean(value),day]
## daily mean using time series
xts.m <- function()
  xtt.d <- apply.daily(xtt,mean)
## benchmark
microbenchmark(dt.m(),xts.m(),dt.withday.m,times=5,unit='ms')


Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq     median         uq        max neval
       dt.m() 159.36342 160.71548 161.628732 162.527193 171.672999     5
      xts.m() 206.63565 207.90692 208.210708 214.023594 225.322446     5
 dt.withday.m   0.00038   0.00038   0.001138   0.001139   0.001518     5
```

So the 2 methods have nearly the same performance. But we dramatically improve performance once we create the grouping factor(dt.withday.m ). So if you have to do other daily summaries , using data.table is a the best choice.

Another point, is `rolling` mean or computing the mean over a giving width time window.As far as I know, I think that xts is unbeatable for rolling mean:

```
  xtt.r <- rollapply(xtt,width=2,FUN=mean)
```